# Magento create a menu and set page for it

Tags: magento

I want to create a menu for my extension in admin panel.

Currently, I create a menu successfully, but I can't link the page I want correctly.

I add the following snippets as follows in config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <nameSpace translate="title" module="nameSpace_myModule">
            <title>...</title>
            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
            <children>
                <form translate="title" module="nameSpace_myModule">
                    <title>Form</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/myModule</action>
                </form>
            </children>
        </nameSpace>
    </menu>
</config>
```

If I set myModule/index, the page of menu can be linked to frontend/default/default/template/myModule/index.phtml.

But I want to set the authority for the menu page, only the people who has logged in can access the menu page. Is it possible? And If I want to link to adminhtml/default/default/template/myModule/index.phtml, how to set it in `<action></action>`?

Thanks